# nth lowest value from from previous k values

Tags: r, sorting, data.table

I have the following data table (used the data.table package).

```
Month   ER
196307  -0.39359311
196308  5.06729343
196309  -1.56222299
196310  2.53955005
196311  -0.85428909
```

For each of the rows, I want to add a column `VR`, which has the second highest value from the previous three values of `ER`. For example for 196311, it would be 2.53955, for 196310 it would be -0.39359311.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another option using non-equi join:

```
DT[, c("start", "end") := .(Month-3L, Month-1L)]
DT[order(ER)][DT, on=.(Month>=start, Month<=end),
    .(Month=i.Month, ER=i.ER, VALUE=x.ER)][
        order(Month, ER), .(VR=VALUE[2L]), .(Month, ER)]
```

output:

```
    Month         ER         VR
1: 196307 -0.3935931         NA
2: 196308  5.0672934         NA
3: 196309 -1.5622230  5.0672934
4: 196310  2.5395500 -0.3935931
5: 196311 -0.8542891  2.5395500
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("Month   ER
196307  -0.39359311
196308  5.06729343
196309  -1.56222299
196310  2.53955005
196311  -0.85428909")
```

Answer (score 4):

In `data.table` you can use `frollapply` to perform rolling calculation.

```
library(data.table)

n <- 2

setDT(df)[, VR := frollapply(shift(ER), 4, 
                    function(x) sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)[n], fill = NA)]
df

#    Month     ER     VR
#1: 196307 -0.394     NA
#2: 196308  5.067     NA
#3: 196309 -1.562     NA
#4: 196310  2.540 -0.394
#5: 196311 -0.854  2.540
```

Answer (score 3):

(@akrun beat me by a few seconds.) Not sure if you have a literal `data.table` (i.e., as in the `data.table` package): in any case, `rollapply` (from `zoo` if you have "regular" data) or `frollapply` (if you are using `data.table`) ...

```
dd <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
Month   ER
196307  -0.39359311
196308  5.06729343
196309  -1.56222299
196310  2.53955005
196311  -0.85428909
")

library(zoo)

dd$VR <- rollapply(dd$ER, width=4, FUN= function(x) sort(x[-4])[2],
                   fill=NA, align="right")
## [1]         NA         NA         NA -0.3935931  2.5395500
```

Since `rollapply` includes the current value, in order to get the second-highest of the *previous* 3 values, I take four values at a time and ignore the fourth (`x[-4]`); @akrun's solution uses `lag()` instead (which seems slightly better, although it does induce a dependency on the tidyverse, which you might not want).

Also @akrun's solution sorts on `-x` (to reverse the order): in this case, since you specified the second-highest of three values, it doesn't matter which order you sort in, but your question's title ("nth lowest from previous k") does suggest that reverse-ordering would be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you know of a way this can be done using the data.table package?

Comment: Suggest `rollapply(dd$ER, list(-(1:3)), sort, fill = NA)[, 2]` where `list(-(1:3))` specifies that only the indicated offsets be used. This gives a matrix with each row sorted so we take the 2nd column.

Answer (score 2):

We could use `rollapply` from `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(VR = rollapply(lag(ER), 3,
         FUN = function(x) x[order(-x)][2], fill = NA, align = 'right'))
```